# How to disable epoll(and to use poll) in netty-all 4.1.3+

Tags: netty, epoll

I want to do performance comparison between epoll and poll, it seems under Linux, netty will always use epoll, is there any way(configuration) for me to use poll to do communication?

Comment: update: by adding **"-Dos.name=win"** to java startup option will use poll other than epoll under linux.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could check sun.nio.ch package, I am using Mac. in rt.jar file, i could find PollSelectorProvider and KQueueSelectorProvider. This link is very old https://blogs.oracle.com/alanb/entry/epoll, I did not try it by myself.But i think it must have some way to change the selector.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried to add **-Dos.name=win** (any value other than "Linux") to java startup option, and it will use poll instead of epoll under linux.

Answer (score 1):

Netty exposes only the [epoll native implementation](http://netty.io/wiki/native-transports.html) for now.

When you're not using that, it takes the JDK implementation, and I believe that the JDK will always use epoll anyway on Linux.

You may want to compare the native epoll implementation of Netty to the JDK one. The advantage of Netty's implementation is that it exposes [TCP options not exposed by the JDK](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/epoll/EpollServerSocketChannelConfig.html) and it allows one to use edge-triggered mode.

You can also check [this page to understand where poll would be a better option than epoll](http://www.ulduzsoft.com/2014/01/select-poll-epoll-practical-difference-for-system-architects/).